# Override xmonad Fade inactive for a window

Tags: xmonad

I use Xmonad-contrib's Fade Inactive and xcompmgr to make the unfocused windows transparent.

Occasionally, I'd like to have a inactive window fully opaque such as when I'm watching a video.

Does anyone have a strategy for having multiple opaque windows using Fade Inactive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution with the help of this Xmonad.hs examples

http://code.google.com/p/xmonad/issues/attachmentText?id=393&aid=4341235945524725336&name=xmonad.hs&token=cc0422d6dd7c329bce14d1f4ca93a3db

You can create a list of windows that aren't faded via FadeIf

an examples xmonad.hs would look like this

```
import XMonad
import XMonad.Hooks.FadeInactive
import Control.Monad (filterM,liftM, join)
import Data.IORef
import Data.List
import qualified Data.Set as S
import qualified XMonad.StackSet as W
import XMonad.Util.EZConfig(additionalKeys,removeKeys)

myFadeHook toggleFadeSet = fadeOutLogHook $ fadeIf (testCondition toggleFadeSet) 0.7
doNotFadeOutWindows = title =? "Call with " <||> className =? "xine" <||> className =? "MPlayer"

testCondition :: IORef (S.Set Window) -> Query Bool
testCondition floats =
    liftM not doNotFadeOutWindows <&&> isUnfocused
    <&&> (join . asks $ \w -> liftX . io $ S.notMember w `fmap` readIORef floats)

toggleFadeOut :: Window -> S.Set Window -> S.Set Window
toggleFadeOut w s | w `S.member` s = S.delete w s
                  | otherwise = S.insert w s


main = do
  toggleFadeSet <- newIORef S.empty
  xmonad $ defaultConfig
  {
  logHook = myFadeHook toggleFadeSet
  , modMask = mod4Mask
  } `additionalKeys`
  [
  ((mod4Mask, xK_f), withFocused $ io . modifyIORef toggleFadeSet . toggleFadeOut
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on it.  :)  If you're running xmonad from darcs, try http://www.ece.cmu.edu/~allbery/FadeWindows.tgz.  (Note that one thing you'll be testing is whether it has more dependencies than are included in the tarball; it's still a work in progress.)  It requires a recent patch to the xmonad core, which I'm not entirely sure has been applied upstream yet.

This archive should be unpacked in your `~/.xmonad` and will place two Haskell source files in `~/.xmonad/lib/XMonad/Hooks`.  (Feel free to unpack somewhere else and verify before copying them to their correct place.)  Documentation is Haddock markup in `lib/XMonad/Hooks/FadeWindows.hs`.  Note especially how to check for the necessary ManageHook patch.

Comment: By the way, as a quick hack you can bind a key to `spawn "xprop -set _NET_WINDOW_OPACITY 4294967295"`; when you run it, the cursor will change to crosshairs, click on the window you want to make opaque.  You'll generally have to repeat it after focus or workspace changes, which is why it's a hack and not a solution.

Comment: I ran into some issues compiling MoreManagerHelpers in your packages using the 2011.2.0.0 Haskell Platform

Comment: Pastebin them, and/or visit `#xmonad` on FreeNode.